# opengl vertices not rendering

Tags: c++, opengl

```
int main() {
using namespace game1;
using namespace graphics;
using namespace maths;
using namespace util;
using namespace std;

Window window("Game 1", 960, 540);
glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.8f, 1.0f);

GLfloat vertices[] = {

    4, 3, 5,
    12, 3, 5,
    4, 6, 5,

    4, 6, 5,
    12, 6, 5,
    4, 3, 5
};

Matrix4f ortho = Matrix4f::genOrtho(0.0f, 16.0f, 0.0f, 9.0f, -1, 1);

GLuint vbo;
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

ShaderProgram s;
s.attachShader(File("res/testVert.vert"), GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
s.attachShader(File("res/testFrag.frag"), GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
s.link();
s.enable();

s.setUniformMat4f("model", Matrix4f::identity());
s.setUniformMat4f("world", Matrix4f::identity());
s.setUniformMat4f("proj", ortho);



while (!window.closed()) 
{
    window.clear();
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    window.update();
}
    return 0;
}
```

I am quite new to opengl, and i am not sure what i am doing wrong. I suspect it has something to do with the vbo or vertexAttribArrayPointer and i've tested lots of things but i cant fins what is wrong. It works with a normal 3 vertex triangle and i'm sure my error is somewhere in main

Comment: Try checking `glGetError()`. What does it say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ortho-matrix that gets defined in the code has a visible range along the z-axes from -1 to 1. The triangle on the other hand is at z=5 which means it is outside of the near-plane/far-plane range.